# Is there any way to detect a shift-click or control-click when a user clicks the browser action button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is a bit of an odd question, but basically, I'm trying to display different pop-up menus to a user depending on how they click my browser action button (the icon to the right of the Omnibar). One way that I thought of doing this is by detecting whether the user is clicking it normally or holding shift as they click it. Is this possible?

If there is no way of doing this, I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to display different menus to the user with a single browser action button. I would rather not make the user select from two options in the actual pop-up window - a single button press would be preferable.

Thanks

Edit: I'm thinking the best way to do this may be to check for the Shift key being pressed using Javascript as soon as the pop-up window is displayed, then display a menu according to that. I'm going to try that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried for 2 hours, but didn't find a solution, too.
I think it's not possible to capture the click event, which opened the popup.